# compare two dictionaries by key to obtain values of matching keys

Tags: c#

I have two dictionaries A and B.

```
A - (a,b) (c,d) (e,f)
B - (a,p) (c,q) (g,h)
```

I want to be able to make a new dictionary C which will be as below -

```
C - (b,p) (d,q)
```

Is there any way I can do this?

This is what I currently have:

```
var C= B.Where(d => A.ContainsKey(d.Key)).ToList();
```

Comment: Post some code so we can help you.

Comment: foreach (var kvp in A) { if (B.ContainsKey (kvp.Key)) { C.Add (kvp.Value, B [kvp.Key].Value); } }

Comment: var C= B.Where(d => A.ContainsKey(d.Key)).ToList();

Comment: @mclaassen That seems to be correct - do you get an error?

Comment: @DStanley Didn't actually run it, just came up with it in my head.

Answer (score 4):

Easy with Linq ;)

```
var query =
    from x in dictionary1
    join y in dictionary2 on x.Key equals y.Key
    select new { Value1 = x.Value, Value2 = y.Value };

var newDict = query.ToDictionary(item => item.Value1, item => item.Value2);
```

However it's not the most efficient approach, since it doesn't take advantage of the dictionary's fast lookup. A faster approach would be something like this:

```
var newDict = new Dictionary<string, string>(); // adjust the key and value types as needed
foreach (var kvp in dictionary1)
{
    string value2;
    if (dictionary2.TryGetValue(kvp.Key, out value2))
    {
        newDict.Add(kvp.Value, value2);
    }
}
```

Comment: @SaurabhSahasrabuddhe, I updated my answer to suggest a more efficient approach

Comment: `join` uses a hashtable internally so the lookup should be fast there also.

Comment: @Magnus, actually, it probably depends on the actual dictionaries. If dictionary2 has a lot of items that are not in dictionary1, the second approach will probably be faster.

Comment: @ThomasLevesque I would say the 2nd approach would always be faster since it doesn't need to populate the internal hashtable's that the join uses. I'm just saying that it probably wont be a very significant difference.